# Sound problems on Elitebook 8540w

Tags: 14.04, sound

I am using HP Elitebook 8540w and Ubuntu 14.04
Stil problem with sound. Alsmost thought I found a solution:

alsactl -F restore

it enabled sound, still have only headphones in sound settings, but the sound is working. headphones are not. After rebooting, speakers are muted again, headphones are working.

How do I fix this, but I want headphones to be headphones that work when I plug the jack in, and I want to see working speakers in sound settings.

I am new to the Ubuntu, so if you need something posted, like info from terminal, please just tell me what to type in...

Thanks in advance

---

**Update on the problem:**

Went to terminal, type "alsamixer". Selected sound card by pressing f6 (my card is HDA Intel MID), unmuted speaker by pressing M button on keyboard. Got my sound back.

Still, no speakers in the sound setting. And speaker and headphones working simultaneously. Problem remains, no speakers in sound settings. After restart, speakers muted again.